# The joined path is located outside of the base path component when trying to resize images in a Django template

Tags: python, css, django, image

I am encountering an issue when trying to resize images within my template using Django daguerre.

The error which I'm getting is:

```
The joined path (C:\media\restaurants\images\Cover_Image-Big-Mac-1242x690_6_2.png) is located outside of the base path component (C:\Users\Luiza\Desktop\unifiedr\media)."
```

Any help is welcome as I am not sure what is wrong here.

My settings:

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'restaurants',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'django_filters',
    'daguerre',
]
```

Below is my urls.py:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from restaurants import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('<int:rest_id>/', views.detail, name = "detail")
] 

urlpatterns += static(
    settings.MEDIA_URL,
    document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT
) + [url(r'^', include('daguerre.urls'))]
```

HTML template:

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load humanize %}
{% load daguerre %}
{% block content %}

<img class="img-thumbnail" src="{% adjust restaurant.img.url 'fill' width=128 height=256 %}" 
onerror="this.src = 'https://icon-library.com/images/photo-placeholder-icon/photo-placeholder-icon-7.jpg';">
```

Model:

```py
class Restaurant(models.Model):`
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'restaurants/images', null = True, max_length = 1000)
```

My project structure is:

[image]

Comment: Hey, what is your BASE_DIR declaration in settings ?

Comment: Hello. My base dir is BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent